# Kernel Smoothing for 0-1 Matrix Data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, kernel-density

I have two data frames of the following form.

```
DATA FRAME 2 df
p1_ht p2_ht perc_won
  175   188    0.377
  188   180    0.518
...
```

`p1_ht` is the height of player 1,
`p2_ht` is the height of player 2
and
`perc_won` is the percentage of games won by player 1 when she is `p1_ht`cm tall and her opponent is `p2_ht`cm tall.

My aim is to investigate the affect height of the players has on the outcome.

I would like to plot a type of heatmap with the following properties: at coordinate `(x,y)`, the value `z` taken is the probability that a player with height `x` beats a player with height `y`.

However, my data comes binned into roughly 2.5cm chunks (I guess corresponding to one inch).

---

**Idea.**
For every location `(p1_ht, p_2ht)`, place a point with `z` value the appropriate element of `perc_won`.
Now use some type of kernel density/smoothing to interpolate (smoothly) between the locations where I have data, eg `(180, 188)` and `(183, 188)`.
However, I don't know how to do this, and haven't been able to find out online.
I'd like to write something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = p1_ht, y = p2_ht)) +
geom_density_2d(aes(fill = perc_won))
```

however, as many of you reading this will be aware, this doesn't work.

---

Any advice on how to do this would be most appreciated!
If possible, I'd like to use the `ggplot` package, as I'm trying to learn how to use that well.

Comment: Maybe [this heatmap example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-simple-heatmap-in-ggplot2/) from R-Bloggers is what you want.

Comment: I had seen that, but there is no smoothing. With the data being quite binned already, it looks a bit weird having such large blocks!

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions? :) -- Seems like it should be quite easy with `ggplot2`, but I can't figure it out...